# PHP registering results in Database from survey selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been here before and it won't be my last time :P. I'm working on a project right now that consists of a survey completed by the user and the results will be saved to a specific userID which is later grabbed by the php file. The current problem I'm having is when attempting to submit the form I'm getting the following error

13

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Number 13 relates the the userID assigned to the test user I'm using. When using ID 12 everything registers without an issue.... Any suggestions?

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', "On");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('location:/login.php');
}
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "animator");
$query= "SELECT iduser FROM `animator`.`user` WHERE idaccount = " . $_SESSION['idaccount'] . ";";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
$info= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$userid= $info['iduser'];
$query= "SELECT idsurvey FROM `animator`.`questionnaire` WHERE iduser = " .$userid. ";";
$result2= mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$info2= mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$surveyid = $info2['idsurvey'];

echo $userid . "<br/>";
echo $surveyid;
$result->close();
for ($i = 0; $i < 18; $i++) {
$qnum= $i + 1;
$qstr= "q" . $qnum;
    $query= "SELECT * FROM `animator`.`question` WHERE idquestion = '" . $qstr . "' AND         idsurvey = 0 ;";
$qresult= mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$qinfo= mysqli_fetch_array($qresult);
$question= $qinfo['question'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM `animator`.`question` WHERE idquestion = '" . $qstr . "' AND idsurvey = " . $surveyid . ";";
$qresult= mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if (mysql_num_rows($qresult) > 0){
$query = "UPDATE `animator`.`question` SET answer = '" . $_POST[$qstr] . "' WHERE idquestion = '" . $qstr . "' AND idsurvey = " . $surveyid . ";";
}
else{
$query = "INSERT INTO `animator`.`question` (idquestion, idsurvey, question, answer)";
$query .= "VALUES ('" . $qstr . "', " . $surveyid . ", '" . $question . "', '" .     $_POST[$qstr] . "');";
    }
    echo $query . "<br/>";
    mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "Inserted question " . $qnum;
}
echo "Questionnaire submitted successfully!";
?>
```

Comment: The dot here, probably should be a comma `$query= "SELECT iduser FROM 'animator'.'user'` plus you have a few others like that.

Comment: can u just post the query which is giving you the error..

Comment: No Fred... Changing them the commas would mess everything up. They are joining the statements together. I believe this query is causing the issue: $query= "SELECT iduser FROM `animator`.`user` WHERE idaccount = " . $_SESSION['idaccount'] . ";";

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being an issue with my database. My partner created a table after the creation of the test user. Because of this there was no record of the person in that table and it caused everything to crash.

This has now been resolved. Thanks for the quick responses!